# Try a speculative, concurrent, lock free, atomic update until abort condition matches

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

Please let me know if you see any performance improvements, bugs, or anything you'd change and why.

```
    public static bool TrySpeculativeUpdate(ref int field, out int result,
        Func<int, int> update, Func<int, bool> shouldAbort)
    {
        SpinWait spinWait = new SpinWait();
        while (true)
        {
            int snapshot = field;
            if (shouldAbort(field))
            {
                result = 0;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                int calc = update(snapshot);
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, calc, snapshot) == snapshot)
                {
                    result = calc;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            spinWait.SpinOnce();
        }
    }
```

Can be used like this

```
    private bool TryIncreaseCapacity(out int newCapacity)
    {
        return TrySpeculativeUpdate(ref _currentCapacity, out newCapacity,
            (currentCapacity) => currentCapacity + 1,
            (currentCapacity) => currentCapacity == _maxCapacity);
    }

    if (this.TryIncreaseCapacity(out newCapacity))
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
```

What I'm really trying to accomplish is the fastest thread safe version of Interlocked.Increment that will stop incrementing at a max value and I will have some way of detecting it stopped incrementing.

Comment: This type of question is possibly better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I put it on code review as well but code review is still beta and does not have many users yet.  I'm hoping code review will take off and I will not need stackoverflow for questions like this in the future.  But for now I would like to get as many eyes on it as possible.

Comment: I wouldn't use equality for a termination condition.  Is there any reason that the abort case doesn't place the actual value in `result`?

Comment: Equality will be fine for termination unless I have a bug because current will never go over max so no need for greater than.  Also I place 0 in the abort case to stay consistent with all other Try methods in the .NET framework that take an int, I guess I could replace with default(int) to be more clear.

Comment: FYI, I tested this against locks and it's about 300%-350% faster on my machine.